# How to let PHP add another line for every form

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I'm using Javascript to create more form fields, to be more specific I'm using jQuery append() to create copies of form fields I already have when a button is pressed.

For example there is an exercise form field, then when someone presses the + button they get another form field to add a second exercise. Now I have to get all these exercises into a PHP file, with no limit so someone could add a 1000 exercises and they would all get sent to my PHP.

I have it setup so jQuery gives them all a name tag with exercisex, the 2nd x being the number of the form field, so the original is exercise1, the second one exercise2, etc.

Now I submit the form and it gets send to another file, submitted.php.
In this file I have it setup for the original form field like this:

```
$exercise1 = $_POST['exercise1'];
```

and to put it in an array

```
$arrExercise = array (
>"exercise1" => $exercise1 );
```

What I'm looking is for a way that PHP automatically adds this:

```
$exercise2 = $_POST['exercise2'];
$exercise3 = $_POST['exercise3'];
```

and adds to the array

```
"exercise2" => $exercise2 
"exercise3" => $exercise3
```

etc. for all the numbers ofcourse

Now obviously I can't add a unlimited amount into this myself so I was wondering how to get PHP to add them automatically according to how many were added.

I see the obvious risk that someone could spam it by adding a million exercises but that's not a concern for the environment this will be used in.

I tried a for loop but got stuck eventually:

I don't remember the exact code but I tried to add a variable, lets call it n, this variable would get a +1 everytime I pressed the + button so if n=1 at the start, pressing the button once makes it 2, then 3, then 4 etc. and then I got stuck thinking I'd still need to add an infinite amount of

$exercise + n = $_POST['exercise' + n];

if that would even work anyways.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: `extract($_POST);` if you can trust the users. Edit: why do you first want to extract the values to then recreate an array? Why not just use $_POST?

Comment: You should use arrays, both on your form like `name=exercise[]` and in php. That will make processing a lot easier instead of checking for unknown variables.

Comment: What's the real problem here? You could write a simple `for` loop that does the job

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried that but couldn't get it work properly, could you clarify a bit on how you would write this loop?

Comment: Can you share what you've tried in the question? Please don't add code to the comment section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved a similar issue yesterday - here's how.....

The 'key' is to get the form names setup before sending to PHP.

*(as you didn't give examples of your form, I will use mine for example - easy enough to port over to your project)*

In my project, the user is allowed to add custom menu (nav bar) items as well as links under it, etc.

The way I solved it was to name things where PHP would get a nicely formed array in the $_POST;

```
<input type="text" name="menu1[Name]" value="">
<input required type="text" name="menu1[data][1][text]" value="">
<input required type="text" name="menu1[data][1][link]" value="">
```

'rinse/repeat' for all the form values that get added (replacing the '1' in the name with your variable) - you would also replace all 'menu1' with your 'exerciseX'

Now, put a 'Submit' button on the page;

```
<button type="button" id="custommenusave">Save Changes</button>
```

A bit of jQuery makes simple work of it....

```
$("#custommenusave").click(function () {
    update_custom_menus();
});
function update_custom_menus() {
    var form = $("#form_custom_menus");
    $.post("../data/ajax.php", 'function=set_custom_menu&' + form.serialize(), function (data) {
        form.submit();
    });
}
```

PHP gets a nice array to work with (I've done a json_encode to make it simpler to see....)

```
{"menu1":{"Name":"'my menu #1'","data":{"1":{"text":"first","link":"https:\/\/example.com","options":"tab"},"2":{"text":"the second link","link":"http:\/\/example2.com","options":"tab"}}},"menu2":{"Name":"'menu #2!!!!'","data":{"1":{"text":"link in menu #2","link":"https:\/\/example.com","options":"tab"}}}
```

Then, pull your user's answers and work with them (of course, you *should* clean any data that comes from a user - no matter how much you 'trust' them!)

This should give you an idea of at least one way (with working code) that you can go.

Comment: This ended up working. For simplification what I did was add the brackets like this in my js file ['+ i +'] and in my original html form field ['+ 1 +']. In the PHP where they are being posted to its without any numbers or brackets. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: YUP!  Though you really didn't need ['+ 1 +'] in the form - you could just do [1] - but it won't make any difference other than your understanding.  Glad it worked for you as well as it did for me (and thanks for the correct answer mark! :)

Comment: Oh woops, just copied ['+ i +'] and inserted 1 instead of i. I did actually simply do [1] in the form, not sure if  ['+ 1 +'] would even work.

Answer (score 0):

name of your input should be an array so you can add multiple inputs by same name

```
<input required type="text" name="exercise[]">

$count = 1;
$finalArray = array();
if(is_array($_POST) && count($_POST) > 0){
   foreach ($_POST as $value) {
       $finalArray['exercise'.$count] = $value;
       $count++;
   }
}
print_r($finalArray);
```